# How to make Postfix apply content filter after expanding aliases?

Tags: email, postfix

On my mail server I have an alias from `root` to my email address (which is handled by the same server). I also have a `content_filter` that uses `${recipient}`. Incoming and outgoing emails work as intended. They get filtered by the content filter with the correct recipient address.

However, when an email is sent to `root` from the local machine, the content filter is passed `root@my.fqdn.com` instead of my email address. After processing the email, the filter hands it back to Postfix, then the local delivery forwards it to the right address.

How can I get the alias to be expanded before the content filter is applied?

#### Current setup

Here is how I currently have the content filter set up (find more details in [INSTALL.md](https://github.com/ajgon/gpg-mailgate/blob/unstable/INSTALL.md)):

- In `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

  ```
  gpg-mailgate    unix    -   n   n   -   -   pipe
      flags= user=nobody argv=/usr/local/bin/gpg-mailgate.py ${recipient}
  127.0.0.1:10028 inet    n   -   n   -   10  smtpd
      -o content_filter=
      -o more_options=omitted
  ```
- In `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

  ```
  content_filter = gpg-mailgate
  alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
  local_recipient_maps = $alias_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps proxy:unix:passwd.byname
  ```

#### Other interesting bits

In `/etc/aliases`:

```
root: testing@phunehehe.net
```

According to the [log](http://notepad.cc/waulaji49), the alias is only expanded in the local delivery agent:

```
Nov 12 10:45:22 server2 postfix/local[29745]: 0AA16792: to=<root@server2.phunehehe.net>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.05/0.01/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as 19F20A53)
```

Comment: Usually the method in which the mail is passed to the content filter is defined in the master.cf, what lines do you have that correspond to the content filter?

Comment: @NickW I added the current setup and link to installation instructions.

Comment: Actually I was expecting to see `no_address_mappings` as one of the options for receive_overide_options, as unless you set that, aliases and virtual users will be expanded.

Comment: Wouldn't that prevent aliases from being expanded altogether? As I said, it seems the alias is only expanded in the final delivery step (local) and I want it to happen earlier.

Comment: No, it would specifically stop aliases, etc from being expanded before the content filter sees it (think group aliases, you don't want a single email that goes to twenty people scanned 20 times unless really necessary)..

Comment: There's something missing, maybe, but the way you call your script should cause expansion.. at least according to http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html and http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html

Comment: I have read those articles before and couldn't find anything wrong :) You have a good point about group aliases, though in this case it makes sense for the content to be processed 20 times, to encrypt the email for each user. Can it be done with a content filter?

Comment: Yes it can.. I'm wondering if the pipe method does get to it before it ends up in the queue, as the advanced methods they talk about tend to be like amavisd, or clamd, available on tcp ports..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11461/discussion-between-phunehehe-and-nickw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/aliases` declares local aliases and thus is only used by the local delivery. According to [ADDRESS_REWRITING_README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#receiving),  only virtual aliases are expanded when mail is received, not local aliases. The solution is to declare [virtual aliases](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps). The local aliases can then be removed.